# How can I wake up paused thread?

Tags: c, pthreads, pause, wakeup

How can I wake up paused thread using only signal() or pthread_kill()?

I think paused thread must recieved some kind of signals to activate, but I don't know what signal have to be sent to paused thread.

//My Terminal

`USER32@myLaptop:~/list$ gcc -o ./temp ./temp.c -lpthread`

`USER32@myLaptop:~/list$ ./temp`

`Starting Thread...`

//My Codes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_t tid;

void *thread_function(void *data){
    tid = pthread_self();
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Starting Thread...\n", sizeof("Starting Thread...\n"));
    pause();
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Success!\n", sizeof("Success!\n"));
}

int main(){
    pthread_t pth;
    pthread_create(&pth, NULL, &thread_function, NULL);

    sleep(1);

    pthread_kill(tid, SIGCONT);

    pthread_join(pth, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pause()` function will return on any signal that can be caught, but you have to set up a signal handler first and catch that signal.

Here is an example:

```
void signal_handler(int sig) {
    printf("Caught signal %d\n", sig);
}

void *thread_function(void *data) {
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handler);
    //rest of your code here
}

int main() {
    ...
    sleep(1);
    pthread_kill(tid, SIGUSR1);
    ...
}
```

[`SIGUSR1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html) is one of the signals reserved for internal use by applications so it is suitable for this case.

[`SIGCONT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html) can be caught, but it is not designed for this, but instead to resume processes that where stopped by [`SIGSTOP`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html).